# Weird output while dereferencing simple numbers

Tags: c++, dereference

My pointer values are acting really weird. If I change one of the pointers addition operators (++ to +=) It messes up the other pointer. (If I said that right).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   //Pointer test 1
   int *ptr, x = 5;
   ptr = &x;
   *ptr += 1;
   cout << *ptr << endl;

   //Pointer test 2
   int *ptr2, x2 = 5;
   ptr2 = &x2;
   *ptr2++;
   cout << *ptr2 << endl;

}
```

Yields and output of : 6, 6

However when I change my first pointer to "++" instead of "+=", like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   //Pointer test 1
   int *ptr, x = 5;
   ptr = &x;
   *ptr++;
   cout << *ptr << endl;

   // Pointer test 2
   int *ptr2, x2 = 5;
   ptr2 = &x2;        
   *ptr2++;               
   cout << *ptr2 << endl;

}
```

I get a value of 0, 5

Why would this be happening?

Comment: `*ptr++` means `*(ptr++)`, not `(*ptr)++`.  Do you understand what `*(ptr++)` means?

Comment: I didn't before, but I do now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*ptr++` means `*(ptr++)` and not `(*ptr)++`, so you are incrementing the *pointer*, not the `int` it points to.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could increment a pointer. Thank you very much. Is there ever a use to increment a pointer then?

Comment: @Saturisk lots and lots of uses.  Whatever good books that you are learning from will show you.

Answer (score 3):

Both program invokes undefined behavior because you are accessing uninitialized memory in both of the program.

`*ptr2++` is similar to `*(ptr2++)` that means in

```
cout << *ptr2 << endl;
```

you are accessing incremented value of `ptr2` which is not initialized in code 1. Same thing is happening with `*ptr1++` and `*ptr2++` in code 2.

Comment: Oh okay. So does that mean when I used *ptr1++ it brought that pointer to an unitialized part of memory so when *ptr2++ was declared it made it all screwy?